# How to change Network Profiles on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, network-adapter, network-profiles

I have a System with different networks that should use different Network Profiles (private and public) for different Network settings (such as different firewall rules).

But the Networks are always shown as "Unidentified Networks" and always are automatically changed to public network with no option to change.

Also the network connections aren't shown in the Local Security Policies (Network List Manager Policies). There only the standard entries are shown.
Changing the standard entries (User can change Location/Name) won't have effect.

I was able to change the network profile via PowerShell (Set-NetConnectionProfile) to private, but after a restart it was set back to public.

Is there any other way, to allocate the network connections to a profile?

Thanks for the support!

OS in use:
Windows 10 IoT Enterprise LTSC 2019 (1809)

Comment: You can work with (enable, remove, etc) Network Profiles with the NETSH WLAN command. Type NETSH WLAN /? for help. Normally if you connect to an existing AP, it will connect as Private if appropriate. With some version (I think perhaps V1809) and beyond, you can use Windows Settings to change from Public to Private or reverse.

Comment: In Windows Settings I'm not able to change it. There is no option in the related menu.

Comment: In V1903 and above there is. So you may need to upgrade

Comment: I have a Windows 10 IoT Enterprise LTSC 2019 so there is no way to upgrade. I also had the same problems with Windows 10 IoT Enterprise LTSB 2016 in the past.